# Generate imbalanced data set in r

Tags: r

In binary classification problem, there are some problems if the classes are not represented equally. This means the number of instances from (+) class is much smaller than from (-) class. For example, you have a two-class classification problem with 1000 instances. A total of 100 instances are from (+) class and the remaining 900 instances are from (-) class, then the ratio of class (+) to class (-) is 1:9.

In this situation, there are many solutions for handling this problem like random under sampling(RUS), random over sampling(ROS), SMOTE, etc..

I want to simulate and compare these methods for imbalanced data set.
So I have to generate imbalanced data set. I made some data like this:

```
sigma1 <- diag(rep(2,3))
sigma2 <- diag(rep(5,3))
a <- mvrnorm(n=500,  mu=c(0,0,0), Sigma=sigma1); minor <- data.frame(a,Y="1")
b <- mvrnorm(n=9500, mu=c(1,1,1), Sigma=sigma2); major <- data.frame(b,Y="0")
data <- rbind(minor, major)
```

In this code, I can handle the ratio of imbalance 1:19 but there is no relationship between y and independent variables.

So, I changed code like generating MAR missing data set

```
set.seed(317+k);       x1 <- rnorm(N, mean=0, sd=1)
set.seed(317+9822*k);  x2 <- rnorm(N, mean=3, sd=2)
set.seed(317+28384*k); x3 <- rnorm(N, mean=5, sd=3)
x <- c(x1,x2,x3);  x.inter <- c(x1*x2, x2*x3, x3*x1)

alpha <- c(2,3,4);  gamma <- c(1.5,1.9,1.3);  beta <- 2;  intercept <- 10
eta   <- intercept + alpha%*%t((x+gamma)^2) - beta*x.inter
pr    <- logistic(x=eta)

Y <- rbinom(N, size=1, prob=1-pr);  Y <- as.factor(Y)

data <- data.frame(x1,x2,x3,Y)
```

But in this code, I have some problem with imbalanced ratio. I know that I should change the 'intercept' for imbalanced ratio, but the ratio is not constant. So when I simulate 1000 times, there are 1000 different imbalanced ratios.

How can I solve this problem? Or Is there some good code for generating imbalanced data for simulation?